# How to get IATA code for the Airline PSS system?

Tags: iata

If we are having airline PSS (passenger Service system) System, how can we registered with IATA and get IATA code. as an example Amadeus is using 1A, Sabre is using 1S, SITA is using XS etc..

Comment: Have you tried asking IATA?

Comment: any contact details

Comment: Finding the contact section on iata.org takes about one point seven seconds (on my phone on mobile data). I‘m sure you‘ll manage!

Answer (score 1):

Try below link, you can type PSS system name and get the code for the same. However, not all PSS are IATA registered.

https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/